# Why is my Android app not showing a permission request for external storage access?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

```java
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    Uri imageData;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ActivityUploadBinding binding;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> permissionLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityUploadBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        registerLauncher();


    }
```

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

```java
    public void selectImage(View view) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission needed for gallery", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Give Permission", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override`your text`
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"1.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"2.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        } else {
            Intent intentToGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery);

        }

    }

    private void registerLauncher() {

        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Intent intentFromResult = result.getData();
                            if (intentFromResult != null) {
                                imageData = intentFromResult.getData();
                                binding.imageView.setImageURI(imageData);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });


        permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                        if(result) {
                            //permission granted
                            Intent intentToGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery);

                        } else {
                            //permission denied
                            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"Permisson needed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

ı try take permission for gallery. When I run this code it did not worked. I cannot see any permission. I did not give any permission and app shows 2. toast message. My other apps it was worked but I cannot find difference between them.